# Why am i only finding image path when retrieving images from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, phpmyadmin

Im trying to retrieve images from my database by using php, my code is connected to the database, all the other information is being retrieved ok, however it is just showing my image path when trying to retrieve images! Anyone know what im doing wrong so i can get my images to show up?

```
$query = "SELECT p.name, p.image, p.price, p.description, p.category_id, ci.quantity   
    FROM products p 
        LEFT JOIN cart_items ci 
            ON p.id=ci.product_id 
    WHERE p.id=? 
    LIMIT 0,1";

 $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
 $stmt->execute();

 $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $name = $row['name'];
 $image = $row['image'];
 $price = $row['price'];
 $description = $row['description'];
$category_id = $row['category_id'];
$quantity = $row['quantity'];
?>
<!-- HTML form for updating a product -->
```

```
 <tr>
    <td style='width:30%;'>Name<?php echo "<div class='product-id' style='display:none;'>{$id}</div>"; ?></td>
    <td class='product-name' style='width:70%;'><?php echo $name; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Image</td>
    <td><?php echo $image; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you storing an image path in the database? Then that's what you'll retrieve when you get the data back out.

Comment: yes in my database i have a column called image, and the image paths for all the values are images/example.jpg                        all my images are stored in images folder

Comment: So, far as I can tell, you didn't prepare/query/execute anything, nor binding anything; not to mention "echo".

Comment: Most developers don't store images in a database, because it's highly inefficient..... they store a filepath to that image on the server filesystem; so read the filepath from the database, and then use that filepath in a `img` tag in html markup, or a function like readfile to send the image to the browser

Comment: @Mark Baker is the filepath im having problems with. at the minute is just shows the file path which is images/example.jpg

Comment: So does a file `images/example.jpg` actually exist relative to your web root?

Comment: @Mark Baker yes the jpg image is stored in an images folder relative to my web root

Comment: So then using `<img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">` should display it in your browser.... if it doesn't, then do a "view source" in the browser, and check what you are getting there

Comment: @Mark Baker still no luck, it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: I have added all the code for that section up above if anyone can spot what is wrong, i changed the code back so that it gives no errors, and it just shows up the filepath in the browser again

Comment: You can't simply do `<td><?php echo $image; ?></td>`.... Use `<td><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></td>` as I said..... this is really HTML 101

Answer (score 0):

As now you have you image path, you can show up the image in html something like: `<img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" >`. Your are doing so because this is the convenient way store/retrieve an image form Database by using their path. Instead of storing the path of the image, storing the whole binary image file in database make it more complex and less efficient.

Comment: I have been able to use this piece of code before:                                <img src=\"".$row["image"]."\"/>            and it has worked, however when i try to use it in this context it isnt working.